# Embed query to data table display in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to display table on my Shiny app based on the Min and Max Range that is take as input from the user.

Below is my data frame `df1`

```
    A   B    C            D
    12  23  Taken       Delivered
    23  32  Taken       Delivered
    32  1   Not Taken   Processing
    21  43  Not Taken   Processing
    12  76  Taken       Delivered
   124  49  Taken       Delivered
    15  14  Not Taken   Processing
    12  15  Taken       Delivered
```

The user first inputs the `min value` and `max value` of `Column A` and `Column B` and Clicks `Apply`, After that the only rows which satisfies the of both `min` and `max` value of both the `Column A` **and** `Column B` should get displayed.

**For Example**

```
Min Value of A = 5,  
Max Value of A = 15,  
Min value of B = 6,
Max Value of B = 15 then, only last two rows should get displayed.  
If none of the input rows satisfies the input values error message **Please 
Select Appropriate Rage** should display.
```

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
fluidRow(

      column(4,textInput("A.Mmin","A min")),

      column(4,textInput("AMmax", "A max"))),
fluidRow(        
      column(4,textInput("BMin","BMin")),

      column(4,textInput("BMin", "BMin")),

      column(4, submitButton(text = "Apply"))),

 fluidRow(        
      dataTableOutput('table')

 )))
```

**Server.R**

```
 library(shiny)
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderDataTable(df1) })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `eventReactive` to get the values when we push the `actionButton` 'Apply' and then `subset`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
```

-ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           numericInput("Amin", "Amin", 5)),
    column(4,
           numericInput("Amax", "Amax", 15))),
                    
           
  fluidRow(        
    column(4,
           numericInput("Bmin", "Bmin", 5)),
    
    column(4, 
           
           numericInput("Bmax", "Bmax", 15)),
          
    column(4, actionButton("button", "Apply"))),
  
  fluidRow(        
    dataTableOutput('table')
    
  ))
```

-server

```
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      cat("Showing", input$Amin, "as min value\n")
      cat("Showing", input$Amax, "as max value\n")
      cat("Showing", input$Bmin, "as min value\n")
      cat("Showing", input$Bmax, "as max value\n")
      
    })
   
    res <- eventReactive(input$button, {
      subset(df1, (A > input$Amin & A < input$Amax) & 
                      (B > input$Bmin & B < input$Bmax))
      
      
    })
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      res()
    })
  }
```

-run

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(12L, 23L, 32L, 21L, 12L, 124L, 15L, 12L), 
B = c(23L, 32L, 1L, 43L, 76L, 49L, 14L, 15L), C = c("Taken", 
"Taken", "Not Taken", "Not Taken", "Taken", "Taken", "Not Taken", 
"Taken"), D = c("Delivered", "Delivered", "Processing", "Processing", 
"Delivered", "Delivered", "Processing", "Delivered")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you:

```
library(shiny)
library(gridExtra)
A <- c(12,23,32,21,12)
B <- c(23,32,1,43,76)
C <-c("Taken","Taken","Not Taken","Not Taken","Taken")
data <- data.frame(A,B,C)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(

    column(4,textInput("AMmin","A min")),

    column(4,textInput("AMmax", "A max"))),
  fluidRow(        
    column(4,textInput("BMin","BMin")),

    column(4,textInput("BMax", "BMax")),

    column(4, submitButton(text = "Apply"))),

  fluidRow(        
    dataTableOutput('table')

  ))

server <- function(input,output){

  df1 <- reactive({
    df1 <- data[data$A > input$AMmin & data$A < input$AMmax & data$B > input$BMin & data$B < input$BMax , ]

  })
  output$table <- renderDataTable(df1())
}

app = shinyApp(ui,server)
runApp(app)
```

[image]
You had few mistakes such as two widgets for `textInput` had the same id --> BMin (i guess copying problem).

Here is the part where i subset the data based on the choice (range min and max) from `textInput`:

```
df1 <- data[data$A > input$AMmin & data$A < input$AMmax & data$B > input$BMin & data$B < input$BMax , ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the code doesn't seem to be working. The app displays all four text boxes i.e `A max`, `Amin`, `BMax`, `Bmin`. but on typing the values it doesn't display anything. Also I can't find the use of `submit button` in your code.

Comment: Code works well, have a look at the data which i used, i have just took first of your 5 rows...And subset button works, you need to keep in mind that there must be correct range choosen for data to display, have a look at the screenshot i have posted below the code...